# SQL Server trigger that doesn't allow deleting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am reading some code for triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER No_DeleteCustomers
ON Customers
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
       RETURN

    RAISERROR('No deleting allowed', 11, 1)
```

But I am confused... isn't `@@ROWCOUNT` used to show the numbers of affected rows in the last statement... How does this prevent me from deleting rows from the table?

Comment: You are correct,  @@ROWCOUNT is used for checking number of rows returned. The IF statement in the trigger will check if the result has zero records then execute the RAISERROR statement. The RAISERROR statement will terminate the transaction and return the message 'No deleting allowed'. This is what prevents you from deleting rows.

Comment: I'm curious why this trigger even exists. Seems like perhaps denying delete privileges on the table would be a better idea.

Comment: @Xedni While you are correct for most users, some users (like sa) can't be denied of any privileges, such a trigger can be helpful to prevent deleting rows by mistake by system administrators (Of course, nothing prevents them from disabling the trigger and then delete, but this is not likely that would happen by mistake...)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through the trigger's code a line at a time to demonstrate how this works:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0                  -- if the number of rows to be deleted is 0 then...
    RETURN                         -- return
                                   -- if still running... 
RAISERROR('No deleting allowed', 11, 1)  -- raise an error to the caller
```

Hope this helps!